# Html not rendering in fullcalender title

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

i am facing issues in showing icons in title. It is showing as it is in the event on calender when i send from laravel as json. i want that it should be change to icon

```
   $events[] = [
                    'id' => $dailyBooking->id,
                   //issue title part that showing as it is (<i class="bi bi-plus" style="color: #007bff"></i> 06:20pm )
                    'title' => '<i class="' . $statusDetails['icon'] . '" style="color: ' . $statusDetails['color'] . '"></i> ' . Carbon::parse($dailyBooking->work_time)->format('h:ia') . " " . optional($dailyBooking->customer)->name,
                    'start' => $startDateTime->toDateTimeString(),
                    'end' => $endDateTime->toDateTimeString(),
                    'status' => $dailyBooking->status,
                    'color' => $statusDetails['color'],
                ];
```

here is my calender initiallization

```
new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    headerToolbar: {
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
                        left: 'prev,title,next',
                    },


                    select: function (arg) {
                        handleNewEvent(arg);
                    },
                    eventRender: function(info) {
                        var title = $('<div />').html(info.event.title).text(); // Decode HTML entities
                        info.el.querySelector('.fc-title').innerHTML = title;
                    },
                    events: [],
                    displayEventTime: false,
                    // eventTimeFormat:"",
                    selectable: true,
                    
                });
```

and here is event adding

```
    // Get the new date after navigating
                                var newDate = calendar.getDate();

                                // Extract the month and year from the new date
                                var newMonth = newDate.getMonth() + 1; // Adding 1 because getMonth() returns 0-based index
                                var newYear = newDate.getFullYear();
                                calendar.removeAllEvents();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: api_url + "calender/monthly-bookings",
                                    method: "POST",
                                    data: {'month': newMonth, 'year': newYear},
                                    success: function (response) {

                                        if (response.status) {

                                            response.events.forEach(function (event) {
                                                // Add new event to calendar
                                                calendar.addEvent(event);
                                            })

                                            calendar.render();
                                            //

                                        }
                                    }
                                })
```

I want that it should convert into icons

Comment: There's no such option as `eventRender` - did you check the documentation? https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc . It sounds like you copied an example from a really old fullCalendar version, without checking against the current version. Surely when you tried to debug this you noticed that the callback you'd assigned to eventRender wasn't ever running?? There's no debugging info in your post though, unfortunately, so it's not clear what you actually tested, or didn't test.

Comment: To achieve your goal you need to use one of the documented [event rendering hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) - most likely `eventContent` (with a callback) or `eventDidMount` would work for you.

Comment: thanks for replying it would be fine if you provide the code

Comment: The way Stackoverflow works is: you make an attempt to write the code you need, and you post it if you get stuck. You already posted one attempt, but it made no sense because it was not based on up to date documentation. Now you have the correct documentation you should be able to attempt the task again. [edit] your question if you're still stuck having actually tried it. We're volunteers here - we'll help you if you _need_ help and have put your own time into it and still had a problem in the code you wrote. In general we won't just do all the work for you, for free. See also [ask].

Comment: Thanku sir i have found soluotion by reading the documantation with eventContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue resolved by `eventContent` function provided by fullcalender

Here is soluotion

```
eventContent: function(element) {
     let CustomDIv = document.createElement('div');
     return { html: [element.event.title] };
 },
```